# Magento 2 Order view Error

Tags: magento2.4

[image]

When I am trying to see the order details i am getting this error in admin pannel.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have added some parameter to one of your constructor. All you have to do is to compile again your code or simply delete the generated folder.